# What is the distribution of $ZX$ when $Z$ is standard normal and $X$ is binary random variable, and $Z$, $X$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X$ be binary random variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$ with some arbitrary pmf. Also, let $Z$ and $X$ are independent. I am trying to find the distribution of $ZX$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $S=ZX$. Then,

$f_S(s) = f_{ZX}(zx)=\sum_{x} f_{Z|X}(z|x)P(X=x)$

But since $Z$ and $X$ are independent, this can be written as

$f_S(s) = \sum_{x} f_{Z}(z)P(X=x) = f_Z(s) \sum_x P(X=x) = f_Z(z)$.

I am not sure if I am making some blunder here, but somehow I don't find this quite correct. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$ZX$ does not even have a density since $P(ZX=0) >0$.  You have to work with distribution functions.
$P(ZX \leq x)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)P(Z \leq x)=1-p+p\Phi(x)$ if $x \geq 0$ and $P(ZX \leq x)=p\Phi (x)$ if $x < 0$ where $p=P(X=1)$.